# How QML access Cpp header define

Tags: qt, qml

I already have a header file with define definitions.

Below are some examples of define.h

> define.h

```
#define STR_STEP0       "step0"
#define STR_STEP1       "step1"
#define STR_STEP2       "step2"
#define STR_STEP3       "step3"
#define STR_STEP4       "step4"
#define STR_STEP5       "step5"
#define STR_STEP6       "step6"
#define STR_STEP7       "step7"
#define STR_STEP8       "step8"
```

I want to use the defined value of define.h file in QML as it is.

I already know about Q_INVOKABLE() and Q_PROPERTY(). With these two methods, the #define variable could not be read directly from qml.

Please tell me how to access variables in define.h in qml.

Comment: What about sending by using signals?

Comment: How can I send the value of #define using a signal?
Please let me know if there is any code you can use as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send by creatin a C++ class. When you emit those defined values on C++, you can read on QML side. Here is an example, you can try:

## main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "sender.h"
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<Sender>("Sender", 1, 0, "Sender");
    Sender sender;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Sender", &sender);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

## sender.h

```
#ifndef SENDER_H
#define SENDER_H

#include <QObject>

class Sender: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Sender(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:

    void send_defined();
signals:
    void sendDefined(QString str);
};

#endif // SENDER_H
```

## sender.cpp

```
#include "sender.h"

#define STR_STEP0       "step0"
#define STR_STEP1       "step1"
#define STR_STEP2       "step2"
#define STR_STEP3       "step3"
#define STR_STEP4       "step4"
#define STR_STEP5       "step5"
#define STR_STEP6       "step6"
#define STR_STEP7       "step7"
#define STR_STEP8       "step8"

Sender::Sender(QObject *parent)
{
}

void Sender::send_defined()
{
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP0);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP1);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP2);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP3);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP4);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP5);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP6);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP7);
    emit sendDefined(STR_STEP8);
}
```

## main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Connections{
        target: Sender

        onSendDefined:{
            console.log(str)
        }

    }
    Button{
        text: "Test"
        onClicked: {
            Sender.send_defined()
        }
    }

}
```